# Best practice: subclass or send intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities almost doing the same thing. The only thing that differs them is a URL to be parsed.

What is considered best practice regarding Android development, subclass just to set the URL or send the URL via an intent?

```
public SuperActivity extends Activity{
    protected String pageUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...lots of stuff...]
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public SubActivityOne extends SuperActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pageUrl = "http://urlOne.com"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public SubActivityTwo extends SuperActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pageUrl = "http://urlTwo.com"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

or

```
public SuperActivity extends Activity{
    private String pageUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        pageUrl = extras.getString("intent_key_url");
        [...lots of stuff...]
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would subclass, but do it slightly differently than you. It's dangerous to put some code in `onCreate` when it's not definitely needed. (You may get lost in your hierarchy and not call exactly what you want to call in the correct order) I would use an overriden method rather than a variable. Do that:

```
public abstract SuperActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...lots of stuff...]
        // instead of using pageUrl, use a method when you need it: pageUrl()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected abstract String pageUrl();
}
```

And your subactivities would look like: (only one shown here)

```
public SubActivityOne extends SuperActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected String pageUrl() {
        return "http://urlOne.com";
    }
}
```

The intent way is good too, but it might become complicated if later on you want to add more differences in your subactivities. With subclasses, it's very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

- if you have multiple activities, which share similar functionality (and/or variables/methods) -> go for **sub-classing.**
- if all you need is to pass a value from the invoking activity, use `intents` (or maybe `Static`)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate code (which is mostly the good thing), make base activity class (make it `abstract`) and put your common code there. Then make your "real" activities extend base class. So option "A" is the way.

Comment: well, option B also avoids duplicate code since i just one string intent and i don't have to create any more classes so that argument seems rather weak?

Comment: Not really. In fact you do not need communication here. all you need are two activities, and the fact it happened they could share 99% of the code, means subclassing makes more sense than intents as the latter adds something to the code that is not justified at all.

Answer (score 1):

A third option would be to make a callback interface and have any class you want implement it.  Something like "PageUrlProvider"

```
public interface PageUrlProvider
{
    String getPageURL();
}
```

Then the concrete implementation would be

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements PageUrlProvider 
{
    private String pageUrl ="http://example.com/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        String myURL = getPageURL();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public String getPageURL() 
    {
        return pageUrl;
    }

}
```

Which option you choose is largely dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.  But this option offers a lot of flexibility.